# How to Login user According to role in yii?

Tags: roleprovider, user-roles

I want to `login` user according to `role`, but i am not getting proper way.
How to `access role` based page in `yii`

so pl z. provide me code with example.

I am waiting Good response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  I have solved these question answer
```

[click here](http://developermaliya.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/how-to-access-login-user-role-based-yii-application/)

Thanks 
hari maliya